# What are good places to start learning web typography and layout?

Tags: website-design, typography, page-layout

I have been a digital designer since 1999. I am self taught.

However; my biggest weakness is spacing, grids and developing pages that feel balanced, as well as have strong typographic hierarchy.

I want my websites to feel like beautiful print documents.

With the web being filled with enormous amounts of resources, where is the best place for me to start learning how to strengthen this.

I feel this is a science, and something that really needs a certain level of methodology applied to it.

Where is the best place to practice or how would you recommend I develop this skill?

Comment: See [The Elements of Typographic Style Applied to the Web](http://webtypography.net/intro/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I totally understand the frustration of being in weak in grids and typography, specially if you are a self taught graphic designer. To me this is very open ended question and that there is no right answer to point out for you.

In my personal experience, it is how you train your eyes and get feedback from your fellow designers would certainly improve your skill you are asking. But, most important is to understand the design principals such as:

1. Balance
2. Proximity
3. Alignment
4. Repetition
5. Contrast
6. Space

I would definitely urge you dig deeper and read more into Meggs' History of Graphic Design. It explains and talks more about styles.

Here is good books that will shape you into what you are asking:

- Thinking with Type by Ellen Lupton
- Type Matters! by Jim Williams
- The Ten Commandments of Typography/Type Heresy
- The Elements of Typographic Style by Robert Bringhurst
- Grid Systems in Graphic Design by Josef Müller-Brockmann
- Design, Form, and Chaos by Paul Rand

These are just the few of the list that will help you.

Wish you luck!

Answer (score 2):

As a supplement / source for inspiration - I'd suggest following Jessica Hische's blog too (http://jessicahische.is). She's definitely one of top typography specialists out right now.

Answer (score 0):

As a compliment to Nomadme's answer (and for a list of web-based resources) you should read [this list](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/04/14/designing-with-grid-based-approach/). I've found that it's a nice introduction for web folks to the world of grids.

Comment: Thanks for this @burnso - only thing I notice is that its from 2007. Would this be considered out of date as the web layout conventions seems to have moved on quite a lot since then. Or would you say its still all very relevant?

Comment: Hmm, that's true. I suppose it might not be as up to date anymore since the advent of the responsive web. But grids are an important part of typography and have been given too little consideration in a lot of modern web design. So I suppose this article in combination with learning about [responsive web design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design) should give you a decent start.

Answer (score -1):

I found the book **100 Ideas that changed Graphic Design** is a great resourtce to place design in its historical context.