# Help and guidance needed to proceed

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, paint.net

I've been 'graphic designing' (I guess) for not so long. I quickly became interested in typography (still am)
I saw some of kurzgesagts videos and saw some really good typography. I tried to recreate it. And I did. I made some things I'm happy with.
[image]
[image]
[image]
I made a few recolours of these,  but my friends told me (and I agree) that this is getting repetitive and I should diversify. 
I am now stuck thinking what to to do. I remember I just saw the text on kurzgesagts video (check his video on string theory time stamps 0:30 and 2:30) and I just recreated it because I was inspired. But what do I do now?
I want to get better at typography, but I have no idea where to start. (Also I use Paint.net because I cant invest money into software like Illustrator) 
I am very confused.

Comment: you recreated it for what purpose? if you're just creating random word posters without a briefing/client/purpose that's difficult to offer some guidance. What design problem are you trying to solve with these? What are they gonna be used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have copied something you have seen. You have succeeded to copy the ideas, too, so you can make your own variations. Watch and copy more to make your palette wider, 1000...10000% wider.

Things called designs are made to create some wanted mood or to to give the wanted impression of something. The client tries to define the wanted mood or impression and the designer makes it happen. When you see ads or other designs, try to analyze what is wanted and how it was made to happen.

Pieces of art are different. The artist decides what is wanted. To create a piece of art one needs something to say by himself and a palette to present it.

Just now there popped out another answer. It seemingly has those a couple of things that I wanted to add + much beyond it, so I stop here.

Start systematic studies and good luck for them!

Comment: Systemsatic studies? But I love the category of 'typography' I was doing. Would you know what type it falls into? This sorta vibrant colours and flat design I just can't resist to look at and admire it. I am 14. I've got a lot of time on my hands. Iearnt to code when I was 12, I've been doing it since. My dream is to be a front end developer, making things looking nice, pretty and responsive. (I love backend too) I want to be good at this kind of typography. I have high hopes! thank you so much

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not a typography specialist, so I can only say it's of decorated engineering type. Single stroke straight letters were and are still used in technical drawings. Colors and highlights are nothing but decorative.

Answer (score 0):

What about studying? Typography is much more than a group of combined sticks. This will help you to understand why those sticks make characters, what's the relation shape/space of each of them, what is the formal relationship between each of them, which are the typographic families, which are the systems of character measurement, which is the spatial relationship of groups of characters, among thousands of other things.

There are some questions and answers here about this subject:

[What are good places to start learning web typography and layout?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36637/120647)

[What makes a design professional?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3503/120647)

[Graphic design beginner: How do you get to the point where a design is in your head?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/66721/120647)

[Tips and resources for beginning designers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/31/120647)

Comment: Hold on, I'm a tad bit confused, what exactly do I read? How will this help me from my odd situation where I only know 1 style?

Comment: Sometimes you lose me Danielillo. What are "combined sticks"?

Comment: Answer updated...

Comment: I think you mean combined lines.

Comment: yes, I used [combined sticks](https://i.etsystatic.com/8511832/r/il/95f1b5/1045484752/il_570xN.1045484752_82yl.jpg) instead lines to make it more obvious

Comment: It's not obvious, it's odd.  Stick usually means a long piece of wood (or some other substance).

Comment: I mean something similar to the image linked in my previous comment

Comment: Lost in translation I think.  Maybe the word you are looking for is stems then?

Comment: I think I understand  what he's talking about :)